# Grep и поиск по содержимому файлов

Tags: expressions, grep, файлы, linux

Нужно найти файлы, содержащие примерно такие строки

```
{if sometext
}
```

Где перед закрывающей скобкой есть или пробелы, или переносы строк.
Комманда

```
grep -E -n -R "\{if[^\}]*?\s+\}" dir/*
```

Но она находит только с пробелами.

Answer (score 1):

```
".*\{if[^\}]*?\s+\}.*"
```

попробуйте так